# Storing just 2 variables in ASP.NET in most easy way

Tags: asp.net

How to store 2 integers between all users in most easiest way, should I use global session variable or cache somehow?

Are these safe methods - is assume lost only if server needs to be rebooted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in the [Application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One way to share state amongst all users on a server is to use Application State. You can read about the different ways you can store state in ASP.NET [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx).